# Can't use classes of C++/CLI project in C# Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I don't have much experience in C++. I am using Visual Studio 2012 to build.

I have:

- A solution with:

  - Static Library in C++ (not in C++/CLI).
  - C++ Tests project (here i am testing all the code from the C++ Static library)
  - Wrapper Project C++/CLI
- Another solution with:

  - C# Test Project

I want to build the first solution and then use the resulting dlls in the C# Unit tests. Later on the C++/CLI will be used in several projects, so I am creating Tests to verify the functionality.

When I created the C++/CLI projected, It created Class1 by default. I didn't delete this class yet, but I created a wrapper for one of the C++ Classes.

When I add this dll to the C# project, the Class1 is visible (I even added a test method and it works), but I can access the Wrapper Class I created.

My C++/CLI project name is:

- MyNamespace.SubNamespace.Managed.MyProject

**The Class1 Code (C++/CLI)**

```
 #pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace MyNamespaceSubNamespaceManagedMyProject
{
public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
                //I used this method to see if the values were going back and forth, and they do
        int TestMethod(int value){return value;}
    };

}
```

**My Wrapper Class.h Code (C++/CLI)**

```
#pragma once
#include "..\C++ProjectFolderPath\MyCPPClass.h"
namespace MyNamespace { namespace SubNamespace { namespace ManagedTest {
ref class MyManagedWrapper
{
private:
    MyNamespace::SubNamespace::UnmanagedTest::MyCPPClass *myInstance;
public:     
    MyManagedWrapper(double value1, System::String ^text1,
        System::String ^text2, array<System::Double>^ double1,
        array<System::Double>^ double2, array<System::Double>^ double3, 
        array<System::Double>^ double4);

    ~MyManagedWrapper();
};
}}}
```

**My C# Test**

```
[TestClass]
public class TEMServiceCppTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var test = new Class1();
        Assert.AreEqual(3, test.TestMethod(3));
    }
}
```

**Class1** works just fine, but I try to do **new MyManagedWrapper()** and It doesn't work. I tried using the fullnamespace too but it is like the class and the namespace doesn't exist.

I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes) page as a reference to create my code. Why would the Class1 class be accessible and not the class I am created? I tried to find if there was some special place I had to register the **Class1** or it's namespace, but I couldnt find any.

**I don't know how to make my MyManagedWrapper class visible my C# code.**

(If you need more detail, let me know and I will add it)

Comment: Your missing a public for "ref class MyManagedWrapper"

Comment: Oh Lord! How I didn't see that! I am using the Visual Studio Wizzards because I am not used to the C++ stuff and I didn't realize of it. If you add it as an asnwer I will accept it. If not, I can just delete my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your missing a `public` for "`ref class MyManagedWrapper`".